# Are the following sentences correct?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, passive-voice

1. I didn't know what **was going** on the second room.
2. I didn't know what **has been going** on the second room.

Comment: They may be correct grammatically but would better reflect common usage if *on* were replaced by *on in*. *on* refers to something put on the room, such as a coat of paint. *on in* refers to what happened in the room.

Comment: Yep, as Anton says, absent the "in" (and if "what" isn't referring to paint or wallpaper) they are not idiomatic.